# Why not taking denormalized tables to the extreme?

Tags: database, relational-database, nosql

Edit: Please do not just down vote. If this is a dumb question, please at least give a short explanation with a down vote. Thanks.

We software developers/database developers have been told to create multiple tables for multiple entity types. Is that just something that makes modelling easier for us or what are the technical reasons for this?

The reason I can think of is that in a denormalized table the data amount is much larger as there will be a lot of duplicate entries. For example there would be 5000 times the same customer in the table for 5000 different customer orders for just one customer. Also keeping the customer data consistent could be an issue.

But let's say data amounts, consistency and aggregation time is no issue, but denormalizing/joining data is. Would it be a viable way to put just all the data in one table (as an extreme) and just work with different views that normalize the data based on the use case as needed?

Comment: you are going to get downvotes/close votes because you are asking a question that is going to generate highly opinionated answers.  There is no "right" or "wrong" answer, it's going to depend on your specific circumstances and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason to normalize an operational database is to avoid anomalies. For example, forgetting to update someone's phone number in every row in which it appears.

It's also a fast way to insert, update, and delete records.

> But let's say data amounts, consistency and aggregation time is no issue

It is an issue and always will be. That's like saying my Ferrari would be faster if safety isn't an issue.

There is a use-case for a highly denormalized database: it's called a data warehouse.